# Using CMSampleTimingInfo, CMSampleBuffer and AudioBufferList from raw PCM stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, core-audio

I'm receiving a raw PCM stream from Google's WebRTC C++ reference implementation (a hook inserted into `VoEBaseImpl::GetPlayoutData`). The audio appears to be linear PCM, signed int16, but when recording this using an AssetWriter it saves to the audio file highly distorted and higher pitch.

I am assuming this is an error somewhere with the input parameters, most probably with respect to the conversion of the stereo-int16 to an AudioBufferList and then on to a CMSampleBuffer. Is there any issue with the below code?

```
void RecorderImpl::RenderAudioFrame(void* audio_data, size_t number_of_frames, int sample_rate, int64_t elapsed_time_ms, int64_t ntp_time_ms) {
    OSStatus status;

    AudioChannelLayout acl;
    bzero(&acl, sizeof(acl));
    acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate = sample_rate;
    audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket * audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket / audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket;

    CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, sample_rate), CMTimeMake(elapsed_time_ms, 1000), kCMTimeInvalid };

    CMFormatDescriptionRef format = NULL;
    status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &audioFormat, sizeof(acl), &acl, 0, NULL, NULL, &format);
    if(status != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create audio format description");
        return;
    }

    CMSampleBufferRef buffer;
    status = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, (CMItemCount)number_of_frames, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &buffer);
    if(status != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to allocate sample buffer");
        return;
    }

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)(number_of_frames * audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame);
    bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = audio_data;
    status = CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList(buffer, kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &bufferList);
    if(status != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to convert audio buffer list into sample buffer");
        return;
    }

    [recorder writeAudioFrames:buffer];

    CFRelease(buffer);
}
```

For reference, the sample rate I'm receiving from WebRTC on an iPhone 6S+ / iOS 9.2 is 48kHz with 480 samples per invocation of this hook and I'm receiving data every 10 ms.

Comment: Hello Tom, is happening the same on my project. Can you enter the avassetwriter configuration? I have done the same than you on AudioStreamBasicDescription, but still distorted. What is elapsed_time_ms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up opening up the audio file that was generated in Audacity and saw that every frame had half of it dropped, as shown in this rather bizarre looking waveform:

[image: before fix]

Changing `acl.mChannelLayoutTag` to `kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono` and changing `audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame` to `1` solved the issue and now the audio quality is perfect. Hooray!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, congratulations on having the temerity to create an audio   `CMSampleBuffer` from scratch. For most, they are neither created nor destroyed, but handed down immaculate and mysterious from `CoreMedia` and `AVFoundation`.

The `presentationTimeStamp`s in your timing info are in integral milliseconds, which cannot represent your 48kHz samples' positions in time.

Instead of `CMTimeMake(elapsed_time_ms, 1000)`, try `CMTimeMake(elapsed_frames, sample_rate)`, where `elapsed_frames` are the number of frames that you have previously written.

That would explain the distortion, but not the pitch, so make sure that the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` matches your `AVAssetWriterInput` setup. It's hard to say without seeing your `AVAssetWriter` code.

p.s Look out for `writeAudioFrames` - if it's asynchronous, you'll have problems with ownership of the `audio_data`.

p.p.s. it looks like you're leaking the `CMFormatDescriptionRef`.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. In fact this confirmed one of the permutations of the settings I tried was valid, and the reasoning behind this is clear. It didn't solve my issue though, please see my answer...

Comment: you were getting mono when you were expecting stereo? good find. pictures are very helpful in audio.

Comment: i have same problem, only my input is 16000 sample rate, input (const void *)audioData frames:(UInt32)len , use like  `CMTime time = CMTimeMake(len / 2 , kSamplingRate);
    CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, kSamplingRate), time, kCMTimeInvalid };
    error = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, len / 2, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &buff);` but still highly distorted and higher pitch.

Comment: Can you start a new question and link it here?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman thanks your response, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708431/using-cmsampletiminginfo-cmsamplebuffer-and-audiobufferlist-from-raw-pcm-16000