# Using CMSampleTimingInfo, CMSampleBuffer and AudioBufferList from raw PCM 16000 sample rate stream

Tags: ios, core-audio

I recevie audio data and size from outside, the audio appears to be linear PCM, signed int16, but when recording this using an AssetWriter it saves to the audio file highly distorted and higher pitch.

```
#define kSamplingRate       16000
#define kNumberChannels     1

UInt32 framesAlreadyWritten = 0;

-(AudioStreamBasicDescription) getAudioFormat {
AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
format.mSampleRate = kSamplingRate;
format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
format.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
format.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;  // mono
format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
format.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(SInt16);
format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
format.mBytesPerPacket = format.mBytesPerFrame * format.mFramesPerPacket;
format.mReserved = 0;
return format;
}

 - (CMSampleBufferRef)createAudioSample:(const void *)audioData frames:    (UInt32)len {

AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd = [self getAudioFormat];

CMSampleBufferRef buff = NULL;
static CMFormatDescriptionRef format = NULL;
OSStatus error = 0;

if(format == NULL) {
    AudioChannelLayout acl;
    bzero(&acl, sizeof(acl));
    acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono;
    error = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &asbd, sizeof(acl), &acl, 0, NULL, NULL, &format);
}

CMTime duration = CMTimeMake(1, kSamplingRate);
CMTime pts = CMTimeMake(framesAlreadyWritten, kSamplingRate);
NSLog(@"-----------pts");
CMTimeShow(pts);
CMSampleTimingInfo timing = {duration , pts, kCMTimeInvalid };
error = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, len, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &buff);
framesAlreadyWritten += len;

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"CMSampleBufferCreate returned error: %ld", (long)error);
    return NULL;
}

AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = asbd.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)(number_of_frames * audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame);
audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = audioData;

error = CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList(buff, kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &audioBufferList);
if(error) {
    NSLog(@"CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList returned error: %ld", (long)error);
    return NULL;
}
return buff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're dividing `len` by two, but your `time` should progress instead of being constant, something like

```
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(framesAlreadyWritten , kSamplingRate);
```

Comment: I add this, still same problem

    UInt32 framesAlreadyWritten = 0;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(framesAlreadyWritten , kSamplingRate);
    CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { CMTimeMake(1, kSamplingRate), time, kCMTimeInvalid };
    error = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, false, NULL, NULL, format, len / 2, 1, &timing, 0, NULL, &buff);
    framesAlreadyWritten += len;

Comment: why still `len / 2`? shouldn't it be `len`?

Comment: this should bug, time is a pts, need generate a progress time

Comment: can you update the question to show your latest code?

Comment: Can you make a small project that reproduces the problem?